# How to use a IBAction to move from one storyboard to another?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to move back to Storyboard Main using an IBAction connected to a UIButton.
In the app delegate is set it up like this:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if doneOnce == false {
        doneOnce = true
        window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    } else {
        window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    }

    return true
}
```

When i'm in storyboard "Onboarding" I try to get back to storyboard "Main":
These are the 3 code snippets I've tried.

```
    @IBAction func tutorialDone(sender: AnyObject) {


    let appDelegateTemp = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegateTemp.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()


    //let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    //let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    //showViewController(vc! as UIViewController, sender: self)

    //let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    //let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController
    //presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But when I press the UIButton which trigger tutorialDone I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tutorialDone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you forgot to set the class on your onboarding `UIViewController`.

Comment: Can you please clarify? I'm on the last step of the onboarding and now try to get back to the main storyboard.

Comment: The scene that is showing your button has put got s custom class set, so it is just a UIViewController. UIViewController doesn't have your `tutorialDone` function, so it crashes

Comment: Still don't understand... So I need to put a tutorialDone function in my UIViewController in "Main"?

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate a viewcontroller from storyboard by using identifier as :

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextViewController") as UIViewController
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Don't forget to give ID to your nextViewController

Refer [this_link](http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2012/11/instantiate-view-controller-using.html)

Comment: I already have that type of code in my comments.  
Tested and same result.